# How to compile UVM library for Questa Modelsim 2020?

Tags: compiler-errors, simulation, system-verilog, modelsim, uvm

I downloaded Modelsim from Intel, the free version (Modelsim-Intel FPGA editition). The free verison is the 32-bit version of Modelsim on Ubuntu 64-bit LTS. I implemented the workaround for this by installing the apt pkg's for i386 arch.

I want to create a testbench in SV using UVM.

This modelsim seems to only have compiled libraries for device support primitives. So I then downloaded UVM 2017-1.1 (IEEE 1800.2) from Accellera.

The documentation only instructs on how to unzip the tar.gz. Once unzipped, I see the source files with uvm.sv & uvm_pkg.sv and the many svh files for the class files (reg, tlm, macros, drivers, monitors, env, etc.).

I do not see any additional makefile or instructions on how to compile for Modelsim.

I then created my own compile script:

```
vlog -64 -lint -modelsimini $(MSI_FILE) -quiet -sv17compat -work $(LIB_UVM) ~/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/uvm_pkg.sv
vlog -64 -lint -modelsimini $(MSI_FILE) -quiet -sv17compat -work $(LIB_UVM) ~/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/uvm.sv
```

I also set up UVM_HOME environment variable to point to the directory that contains the src folder in it.

The error I get on my compile script is this:

```
Error: ** while parsing file included at /home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/uvm_pkg.sv(26)
** while parsing file included at /home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/uvm_macros.svh(82)
** at /home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/macros/uvm_tlm_defines.svh(642): Cannot open `include file "tlm1/uvm_tlm_imps.svh".
** Error: ** while parsing file included at /home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/uvm_pkg.sv(30)
** at /home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/dpi/uvm_dpi.svh(40): Cannot open `include file "dpi/uvm_hdl.svh".
** Error: ** while parsing file included at /home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/uvm_pkg.sv(30)
** at /home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/dpi/uvm_dpi.svh(41): Cannot open `include file "dpi/uvm_svcmd_dpi.svh".
```

I can see the svh files within the src folder, they are nested within the folders indicated. I can only assume the vlog compiler is looking at my local project folder and not the folder where uvm_pkg.sv is located in.

I then tried to use the +incdir+$(UVM_HOME) flag which points to the src file. I still get the same errors.

```
** Error: ** while parsing file included at /home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/uvm_pkg.sv(35)
** at /home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/seq/uvm_seq.svh(32): Cannot open `include file "/home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1//seq/uvm_sequence.svh".
** Error: ** while parsing file included at /home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/uvm_pkg.sv(35)
** at /home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1/src/seq/uvm_seq.svh(33): Cannot open `include file "/home/deadsupra/rtl_lib/UVM-18002-2017-11tar/1800.2-2017-1.1//seq/uvm_sequence_library.svh".
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have searched for any proper method to compile UVM, a lot of it seems to point to +incdir. But a lot of examples are for older versions of modelsim and older UVM 1.1 or 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In my compile script I gave it the right path to the `.sv` files. However, my earlier version of the path in the environment variable `UVM_HOME` did not set the directory including the src folder. Once I reran my source.sh script and updated the environment variable, the `.svh` files were able to locate the dependency files appropriately.

It was in front of me the whole time as well with the error message showing no `src` folder in the path it was looking in: `..../1800.2-2017-1.1//seq/uvm_sequence.svh`

Answer (score 0):

Xilinx Vivado 2020.1 Supports UVM 1.2 and many features of Systemverliog. It supports the same in WebPack (Freeware) Version. I developed a tool "tbengy" to generate a UVM TB and Makefile. You can read the instructions on https://github.com/prasadp4009/tbengy